# Inefficiency of Numpy Argwhere

Tags: python, numpy

I am learning about methods like `argwhere` and `nonzero` in NumPy.  It appears that  the`numpy.nonzero(x)` the function returns a tuple of one-dimensional `ndarray` objects so that the output of this function could be used for indexing.

I have not ready the `C` source code of `nonzero` because I don't know how to find it.  However, I imagine that the `nonzero` function will construct an `m` by `ndim` `ndarray` object (for some `m` that depends on the input) that will hold the indices of nonzero elements of `a`.  To verify that this guess is correct, I tried:

```py
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import Generator, PCG64
rg = Generator(PCG64())
x = rg.integers(0,2,(10000,10000))
y = np.nonzero(x)
print(y[0].base is y[1].base)
z = y[0].base
print(type(z),z.shape)
print(np.array_equal(z[:,0].reshape(-1),y[0]))
print(np.array_equal(z[:,1].reshape(-1),y[1]))
```

which outputs:

```
True
<class 'numpy.ndarray'> (50005149, 2)
True
True
```

My interpretation of the above is that the `nonzero` function does construct a single `m` by `ndim` sized array.

There is also a `np.argwhere(x)` function.  Unlike `np.nonzero`, it will return an `m` by `ndim` size array, not a tuple.  Reason suggests that `argwhere` and `nonzero` would be practically the same, except that `nonzero` returns the output in a slightly different format.   To my surprise, `argwhere` seems to be implemented as follows (according to: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argwhere.html):

```py
# nonzero does not behave well on 0d, so promote to 1d
    if np.ndim(a) == 0:
        a = shape_base.atleast_1d(a)
        # then remove the added dimension
        return argwhere(a)[:,:0]
    return transpose(nonzero(a))
```

Because the `nonzero` function returns a tuple, it seems like the `transpose` operation in `argwhere` is going to require an extra copy for no reason.  A quick experiment with a timer suggested that this copy does happen.

**Question**
Can someone explain why the `argwhere` function is implemented this way?  For example, the alternative

```py
def faster_argwhere(a):
    # nonzero does not behave well on 0d, so promote to 1d
    if np.ndim(a) == 0:
        a = shape_base.atleast_1d(a)
        # then remove the added dimension
        a=a[:,:0]
    return np.nonzero(a)[0].base
```

already seems better, since:

```
x = rg.integers(0,2,(10000,10000))
t_0 = time.perf_counter()
y = np.argwhere(x)
t_1 = time.perf_counter()
z = faster_argwhere(x)
t_2 = time.perf_counter()
print('elapsed time for argwhere:' + str(t_1-t_0) + ", and for other method:" + str(t_2-t_1))
print(np.array_equal(y,z))
```

yields:

```
elapsed time for argwhere:2.175326200000086, and for other method:1.7338391999999203
True
```

Comment: Huh. Perhaps you can suggest this as a pull request (or an issue) to numpy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I looked at `nonzero` some time ago, I saw that it performed two passes.  First a `np.count_nonzero` (in the c-api version) to determine the return size, and a second to actually get the indices.  I didn't pay attention as to whether it allocated `n` independent arrays or just one 2d.  But now that you mention it, the arrays are views of a common 2d array:

```
In [464]: x = np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)  
In [468]: idx = np.nonzero(x%3==0)                                                                   
In [469]: idx                                                                                        
Out[469]: (array([0, 0, 1, 2]), array([0, 3, 2, 1]))
In [470]: idx[0].__array_interface__                                                                 
Out[470]: 
{'data': (54070800, False),
 'strides': (16,),
  ...}
In [471]: idx[1].__array_interface__                                                                 
Out[471]: 
{'data': (54070808, False),
 'strides': (16,),
 ....}
```

The data pointer is `8` larger, and strides `16`, consistent with that.

For a 3d array:

```
In [472]: x = np.arange(24).reshape(2,3,4)                                                           
In [473]: idx = np.nonzero(x%3==0)                                                                   
In [474]: idx[0].__array_interface__                                                                 
Out[474]: 
{'data': (54163904, False),
 'strides': (24,),
In [475]: idx[1].__array_interface__                                                                 
Out[475]: 
{'data': (54163912, False),
 'strides': (24,),
In [476]: idx[2].__array_interface__                                                                 
Out[476]: 
{'data': (54163920, False),
 'strides': (24,),
```

The same thing - 24 strides etc.

I don't know the history of these functions.  Has `nonzero` always returned views of a common 2d array?  Recent versions have tried to ween us away from using `np.where` instead `np.nonzero`.  We don't yet have a `np.arg_nonzero` :)

As you note, the `nonzero` tuple works well as index.

```
x[np.nonzero(x)]
```

Novices often don't appreciated this, and instead think they need a list of tuples.  But to use those they have to iterate

```
 for tup in [(0,0),(1,0),...]: print(x[tup])
```

The `argwhere` isn't quite right for that:

```
In [480]: x[idx]                                                                                     
Out[480]: array([ 0,  3,  6,  9, 12, 15, 18, 21])
In [481]: np.transpose(idx)                                                                          
Out[481]: 
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 3],
        ....
       [1, 2, 1]])
In [482]: [x[tuple(i)] for i in np.transpose(idx)]                                                   
Out[482]: [0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21]
```

I don't know if that worked without the `tuple` in earlier versions or not; it raises an error now.

So yes it might be possible to make `argwhere` more efficient, by accessing the `nonzero` base directly.  But what's the benefit?

```
In [487]: idx[0].base                                                                                
Out[487]: 
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 3],
         ...
       [1, 2, 1]])

In [492]: timeit x[idx]                                                                              
2.46 µs ± 8.17 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
In [493]: timeit [x[tuple(i)] for i in idx[0].base]                                                  
21.7 µs ± 836 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
In [494]: timeit [x[tuple(i)] for i in np.transpose(idx)]                                            
33.2 µs ± 94.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Ultimately `why` questions like this can only be answered by comments in the code or discussions in the developer's forums or the github issues.

Comment: A search of the release notes shows something about the base in `nonzero` in 1.10, and the refinement for 0d array in `argwhere` around 1.15.